# Apple reject app to sign in failed but it is working fine with me

Tags: iphone, swift

We are still unable to login to review your app
But it working fine with me apple suggest it is IPV6 problem when we call api to login its response failed and give an alert login failed but in my case api response never failed . Is the server side issue ?  It is possible that server not support IPV6 my server side is http://brightowl.pro
Kindly solve this problem my app rejected 7 to 8 times thanks

Comment: I'm not so sure there's an answerable question in here.

Comment: why i am ma very stressed, if you know the answer kindly describe

Comment: well what kind of archx u have?do you have some of kind of proxy before u call ur  actual api?i tried creating account in ur website it worked for me.i am   not an expert on apple app review process,you can checkout some link for that in apple website.but what else did they say about the error.apart from few suggestions.It would be impossible to give you a solution.coz its a pretty big troubleshooting problem which you can not be sure on to get solved over this platform.I am sorry man!!

Comment: Wait !! if you are using your current login method it does not seems to be secure at all you are exposing password and everything.There is no security in ur login method,I can see in the request and response what is my password,thats one thing you should probably tackle first if you wana save your customer details secure

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your host is [not reachable via the IPv6 address in DNS](https://gist.github.com/sdstrowes/fe45779e4941e3289ec60546e89fae08). The "!H" on the final line of this gist is specifically a notification from the final hop that it cannot route toward the address.

You may want to check your DNS configuration, and that the AAAA record has the correct value for your host/domain. One hint that you might have misconfigured the AAAA record is that the IPv4 address listed in DNS for your domain appears to be [owned by GoDaddy](http://bgp.he.net/ip/97.74.197.239), but that is not true for [the IPv6 address](http://bgp.he.net/ip/2a01:7c8:eb:0:95:170:76:162).

That may or may not be what's actually tripping up the review process, but this is a good problem to fix.